# AJAX requests on Chrome using jQuery freezes page until they all complete

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-chrome, freeze

Code below works well on Firefox - displays progress bar which progresses on every file being uploaded, meanwhile in Chrome, it only displays progress bar at the end of transaction, also when I click "submit" button it freezes up until function completes.

```
var max = files.length + 1;
var progress_step = 0;
$.post(form.action, $(form).serialize(), function(response){
  var data = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
  if ("errors" in data){
    //...;
  }
  else if ("work_id" in data){
    var work_id = data.work_id;
    //initial increase of progress once Work was created
    progress_step = progress_step + 1;
    progress(progress_step, max);

    $.each(files, function(index, obj){
      uploadFile(work_id, obj);
      progress_step = progress_step + 1;
      progress(progress_step, max);
    });
  }
});
```

...

```
function uploadFile (w_id, obj) {    
  var base64_start = obj.src.indexOf(',') + 1;
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/works/upload_image',
    data: {work_id: w_id, pic: obj.src.substr(base64_start), pic_type: obj.file.type},
    processData: true,
    timeout: 60000,
    async: false,
    dataType: 'text'
  }); 
}
```

Comment: The title here is misleading. This is a synchronous request, and AJAX stands for Asynchronous JavaScript And XML. This is a nitpick, but some people may be looking for asynchronous performance issues.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you don't want it to freeze, change `async: false` to `async: true`. Since this will make an asynchronous request, it might break the functionality of your progress bar, because it will move on to the next line of code before the request has completed. To fix this, use

`success: function() { /*code in here*/ }`

to put the code you want to activate when the request is finished.

Answer (score 3):

Using `async: false` will freeze the page until the server replies.
Do not use it.

Get rid of that line and it will work fine.
However, it will be asynchronous, so you'll need to move your loop into the `success` callback.

Answer (score 1):

Following SLaks remarks, I got the following to work with a recursive ajax call.
The recursion is occurring on the ajax success callback.

```
var notesText = "";
        document.addEventListener('eInspListSynch', function (e) {

            notesText += "Number of records to save : " + inspRecordList.length.toString() + "\r\n";
            $("#SynchNotes").html(notesText);

            $("#synchProgressBar").progressbar({
                value: 0,
                max: inspRecordList.length
            }).show();

            // Recursive call.
            SendARecord(0);            

        });

        // Recursive call required here because Chrome will set browser updates off when asynch false is set for ajax calls.
        function SendARecord(currentRecord)
        {
            oneInspRecord.recordId = 99;
            oneInspRecord.weatherId = 5;
            var cntOfInspSaved = 0;
            oneInspRecord.contractorName = "CYoung";

            var pbVal = $("#synchProgressBar").progressbar("value");
            $("#synchProgressBar").progressbar("value", pbVal + 1);
            $("#synchProgressBar").show();

            $.ajax({
                type: "Post",
                url: '@Url.Content("~/SiteVisitInspection/SaveOneSiteVisitInspection/")',
                dataType: 'text',
                success: function (res) {
                    // If successful then delete the record from local cache.
                    notesText = inspRecordList[currentRecord].recordId.toString() + " written to server.\r\n" + notesText;                    
                    currentRecord = currentRecord + 1;
                    $("#SynchNotes").html(notesText);

                    if (currentRecord < inspRecordList.length) {
                        SendARecord(currentRecord);
                    }
                    else {
                        $("#synchProgressBar").hide();
                        notesText = "Completed synchronization.\r\n" + notesText;
                        $("#SynchNotes").html(notesText);
                        return;
                    }


                },
                error: function (error) {
                    console.log("Error in SaveOneSiteVisitInspection.");
                },
                data: oneInspRecord//,
                //async: false

            })


        }
```